# Is there a way to convert a project into a VS template?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I created a cool looking form theme and that is very minimal and does not include any code that isn't related to the UI. So I was thinking it would be perfect for a Visual Studio template so I can include it in my project so I don't have to copy and paste the elements and code back into every form I add in the project. The project is WinForms.

If their is not a cut and dry way then I will just duplicate it as a template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Templify](http://opensource.endjin.com/templify/), and a [blog post introducing it](http://blog.endjin.com/2010/10/introducing-templify/).

I'm not sure if it will work on a per-form basis, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps look into the [Export Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.EXPORTTEMPLATEWIZARD%29&rd=true) feature of Visual Studio.